# Semantic search in P2P networks

Tags: search, semantics, p2p

we are doing a project that involves semantic search in P2P networks. Basically we want to do a file searching/sharing mechanism that semantically relates files based on the data. we are using RDF to represent the files' metadata. We are stuck with the database part. every peer has a local repository that it uses to store metadata. how do we implement this store? please help..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/). It is an open source project for storage and querying of RDF data.